# How do I correctly reference an attribute of the current element passed into knockout.JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Working on a little feedback form and I'm new at the Knockout/jQuery game so I'm sure this is a syntax error.

### Goal / Background

- I have a feedback form, part of which includes a list with feedback types. The actual text of the feedback type I'd like to use is stored in the "Title" attribute of the LI tags.
- I'd like to pass an onclick from each of a set of LI tags denoting the type of feedback.
- I would like knockout to receive this onclick event with the calling element
- I'd like the ViewModel function to update the ViewModel's feedback type based on the content of the LI's title attribute
- I'd then like to remove a class from all the list and apply it to the selected element.

  - I already have jQuery that does this; just want to incorporate it into the model change.

### What I Have So Far

The relevant part of the HTML Feedback Form (the UL list):

```
        <ul class="thumbnails" id="feedbackList">
            <li class="feedbackItem" id="feedbackItemPraise" title="Praise" data-bind="click: updateFeedbackType"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>Praise</li>
            <li class="feedbackItem" id="feedbackItemCriticism" title="Criticism" data-bind="click: updateFeedbackType"><i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i>Criticism</li>
            <li class="feedbackItem" id="feedbackItemProblem" title="Problem" data-bind="click: updateFeedbackType"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i>Problem</li>
            <li class="feedbackItem" id="feedbackItemQuestion" title="Question" data-bind="click: updateFeedbackType"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i>Question</li>
        </ul>
```

The ViewModel so far (including some irrelevant parts):

```
var FeedbackViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.manualEMailAddress = "MyEmail@MyProvider.com";
    self.manualApplicationName = "MyApplication";
    self.username = ko.observable($("#feedbackUsernameFromServer").val());
    self.feedbackType = ko.observable("Praise");
    self.wantsFollowUp = ko.observable(true);
    self.enteredName = ko.observable("");
    self.feedbackText = ko.observable("");
    self.userNameCaptured = ko.computed(function () { return self.username().length > 3; }, self);
    self.mailToLink = ko.computed(function () { return "mailto:" + self.manualEMailAddress + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent(self.feedbackType()) + encodeURIComponent(" for ") + encodeURIComponent(self.manualApplicationName) + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(self.feedbackText()) }, self);
};

var feedbackViewModel = new FeedbackViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(feedbackViewModel, document.getElementById("feedbackModal"));
```

The current jQuery to change the style (not linked to the model yet):

```
$("#feedbackList li").click(function () {
    $("#feedbackList li.feedbackItem-Highlighted").removeClass("feedbackItem-Highlighted");
    $(this).addClass("feedbackItem-Highlighted");
});
```

What I think I need to add to the ViewModel, but doesn't quite work:

```
self.updateFeedbackType = function (elementToChangeTo) {
    self.feedbackType($(elementToChangeTo).attr("title"));
    $("#feedbackList li.feedbackItem-Highlighted").removeClass("feedbackItem-Highlighted");
    $(elementToChangeTo).addClass("feedbackItem-Highlighted");
};
```

This results in feedbackType being turned into an undefined and the visual change not happening.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just needed that function in the definition of the vm.

Here's a jsfiddle that seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/gN3HV/

Update: Here's a fiddle which better leverages knockout and properly accomplishes the goal:

http://jsfiddle.net/gN3HV/7/

Comment: +1 for using JSFiddle -- I always forget about this awesome tool.

The problem is still evident in this revision that I created: http://jsfiddle.net/gN3HV/5/

The issue seems to be the updating of the observable. I think it errors out on me and therefore the jQuery never fires?

Comment: The approach so far doesn't really leverage knockout fully. Generally, when you write knockout code, you try to avoid manual DOM manipulation. Here's a simplified fiddle showing a more generic knockout approach to the problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/gN3HV/7/

Comment: daedalus28 and @Kato: Thanks for the knockout education as well as the solution. I'm thinking I should turn the web-font icon references (<i class="icon-name"></i>) into part of a multi-dimensional array that lists the choices and their corresponding icons. Does this make sense or am I making it to complicated again?

Comment: Nevermind, I was definitely overcomplicating. Now that I see what I can do I'll just re-assess my css class names (better anyway) and pick them based on the item selected via $data. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`elementToChangeTo` returns the FeedbackViewModel (same as `this`) and not the element clicked on--the behavior is a bit different than jQuery.

The second argument passed into `updateFeedbackType` will be an event, so you could use `$(event.target)` to get a reference to the clicked element.

```
self.updateFeedbackType = function (view, event) {
    var $elementToChangeTo = $(event.target);
    self.feedbackType($elementToChangeTo.attr("title"));
    $("#feedbackList li.feedbackItem-Highlighted").removeClass("feedbackItem-Highlighted");
    $elementToChangeTo.addClass("feedbackItem-Highlighted");
};
```

However, @daedalus28 has addressed the larger problem, which is that you're not utilizing knockout.js's strengths and are over-complicating the process. You don't really need both to solve this simplistic condition.